# Can I change my map.resources line in routes.rb to change the model name in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

At the moment, I have this line in `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :usernotes
```

so my paths are `/usernotes/new` etc

But I realise now I want them to be like `/notes/new`

Is there a way to change the line in `routes.rb` to do this?

Comment: You should specify the Rails version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's super-easy:

```
map.resources :usernotes, :as => 'notes'
```

See section 3.7.4 here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing (for Rails 2.3.x)

or here for Rails 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: I added the Rails version to clarify the answer. Please note that in Rails 3 the route is not called on `map.`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you `/notes` and `/notes/new` etc

```
resources :notes, :controller=>"UserNotes"
```

You'll use new_note_path etc